# Oracle SQL - Multiple return from case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I may be trying it wrong. I am looking for any approach which is best.

**Requirement:**

My Query joins 4-5 tables based on few fields.

I have a column called product id. In my table there are 1.5 million rows. Out of those only 10% rows has product ids with the following attribute

```
A300X-%
A500Y-%
```

300,500, 700 are valid model numbers. X and Y are classifications. My query picks all the systems.

I have a check as follows

```
CASE
WHEN PID LIKE 'A300X%'
THEN 'A300' 
...
END AS MODEL
```

Similarly

```
CASE
WHEN PID LIKE 'A300X%'
THEN 'X'
...
END AS GENRE
```

I am looking for the best option from the below

1. How do I Combine both case statement and add another[third] case which will have these two cases. i.e

> ```
> CASE 
>     WHEN desc in ('AAA')
>          First Case
>          Second Case
>     ELSE
>          don't do anything for other systems
>     END
> ```

2. Is there any regex way of doing this? Before first - take the string. Look for X, Y and also 300,500,700.
3. Is there any other way of doing this? Or doing via code is the best way?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Sample desc:

```
AAA,
SoftwARE, 
sw-app
```

My query picks all the desc. But the case should be running for AAA alone.

And Valid models are

```
A300X-2x-P
A500Y-5x-p
A700X-2x-p
A50CE-2x-P
```

I have to consider only 300,500,700. And the above two cases.

Expected result:

```
MODEL     GENRE
A300      X
A500      Y
A300      Y
```

Comment: Please show more sample data.  If you require the two columns which you have aliased in those two `CASE` expressions, then it isn't clear why you want just a single column.

Comment: Are you aware (I guess you are, but had to ask) that `%` functions as a wildcard, meaning that `123abcdefg%` and `123456789dfdgffdg` will both match `123%` (in connection to a `like`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added some more data. Please check.

Comment: @Gops AB: No, what Tim says is that we don't understand how you want two things at a time returned from `case when`. So please show the expected result, i.e. not only a list of strings, but also the columns the result shall contain. Will there be a model column? Will there be a genre column? Will there be another column combining these somehow? Please show.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I added expected output columns. Please check and let me know. Yes, there will be a model column and a genre column. No combined columns.

Comment: Each column in the resultset will require a *separate* expression in the SELECT list of the query. It's not possible for a single expression (CASE or otherwise) to return more than one value. (See the answer I provided. The `LIKE` comparisons in my answer aren't necessarily the best way to test for the conditions needed for this use case; the example demonstrates combining conditions and nesting CASE expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Q: How do I Combine both CASE  <strike>statement</strike> expressions

Each `CASE` expression will return a single value. If the requirement is to return two separate columns in the resultset, that will require two separate expressions in the SELECT list.

For example:

```
DESC  PID           model_number  genre
----  ----------    ------------  ------
AAA   A300X-2x-P    300           X 
AAA   A500Y-5x-p    500           Y
AAA   A700X-2x-p    700           X
AAA   A50CE-2x-P    (NULL)        (NULL)
FOO   A300X-2x-P    (NULL)        (NULL)
```

There will need to be an expression to return the `model_number` column, and a separate expression to return the `genre` column.

It's not possible for a single expression to return two separate columns.

---

Q:  and add another[third] case which will have these two cases.

A `CASE` expression returns a value; we can use a `CASE` expression almost anywhere in a SQL statement where we can use a value, including within another `CASE` expression.

We can also combine multiple conditions in a `WHEN` test with `AND` and `OR`

As an example of combining conditions and nesting CASE expressions ditions...

```
 CASE 
 WHEN (    ( t.PID LIKE '_300%'  OR t.PID LIKE '_500%'  OR t.PID LIKE '_700%' )
       AND ( t.DESC = 'AAA' )
      )
 THEN CASE 
        WHEN ( t.PID LIKE '____X%' )
        THEN 'X'
        WHEN ( t.PID LIKE '____Y%' )
        THEN 'Y'
        ELSE NULL
      END
 ELSE NULL
 END AS `genre`
```

There are other expressions that will return an equivalent result; the example shown here isn't necessarily the best expression. It just serves as a demonstration of combining conditions and nesting CASE expressions.

Note that to return another column `model` we would need to include another expression in the SELECT list. Similar conditions will need to be repeated; it's not possible to reference the `WHEN` conditions in another `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data, logic such as this would work:

```
(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(PID, '^A[0-9]{3}[A-Z]-')
      THEN SUBSTR(PID, 1, 4)
      ELSE PID
 END) AS MODEL

(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(PID, '^A[0-9]{3}[A-Z]-')
      THEN SUBSTR(PID, 5, 1)
      ELSE PID
 END) AS GENRE
```

This assumes that the "model number" always starts with "A" and is followed by three digits (as in your example data).  If the model number is more complicated, you may need `regexp_substr()` to extract the values you want.

Comment: Great, Looking good. Let me try this and get back to you immediately

Comment: How do you fit two results into a single field? I'm asking because, theoretically, they could both return a result, can't they?

Comment: Gordon, Your solution used regex which is a lot way better than what I thought. But still it does two checks. Isn't?

Comment: @GopsAB . . . You could do one check if you put the expression in the subquery.